# Is it possible to insert php code in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, errorlevel

I have written an PHP file editor and interpreter (basically the output window in as an iframe) in PHP (HTML,CSS,JS [ace.js]).

Now I want to give the user an option to modify the level of error reporting without changing the contents of the file. Normally, one would use the function `error_reporting` to it by calling the method at the start of the php file...but here I do not want to change the contents of the file.

Is there any way I can dynamically run PHP code in order to prepend `error_reporting(level);` at the start of the file or maybe is there any other workaround to solve the same problem?

Please let me know if any more information is needed. By default, the iframe's src points to the file the editor is editing.

Comment: Well for starters, there is https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: Of course your itself iframe could also load a script that sets the error reporting, and then includes whatever script file the user was editing afterwards (name of the file could be passed as a parameter.)